# Change logger level depending on status

Tags: java, logging, refactoring, slf4j

Let's say we have some method sending email messages with status level of the message:

```
void sendEmail(Level level, String message) {
    ...
}
```

The levels can be of three types:

```
enum Level {
   Info,
   Warn,
   Error
}
```

Along with the sending email itself we want to log message using the standard logger, but we also want to respect message level, so for `Info` level we want to use `INFO` logger level and so on.

I've faced with a viewpoint, that we should not do logging inside `sendEmail`, because the method itself is "generic" while internally it performs "a specific behaviour":

```
void sendEmail(Level level, String message) {
    switch (level) {
       case Info: LOGGER.info("Sending message {}", message); break;
       ...
    }
    // other email sending stuff...
}
```

But rather should log externally when we invoke this method, say:

```
LOGGER.error("Sending message: {}", message);
sendEmail(Level.Error, message);

...

LOGGER.warn("Sending message: {}", message);
sendEmail(Level.Warn, message);
```

Be aware also, that `level` is not only for logging, but it is used inside the email content. Take also into account that the example is very simplified: the actual message of the logger is much more complicated, containing several other parameters of the enclosing method.

Being on a mild position I deem both approaches as equal. Being a little bit more strict I would say that the suggested approach with many LOGGER invocations where the log message is always the same (!) is a pure code duplication.

Any pros & cons? Closing as "opinion based" would be also fine for me, as it means that my "mild" position is also correct.

Comment: What logging FW are you using? SLF4J sadly doesn't provide a `Logger.log(Level, Message)` function where LOG4J does. You could write a small helper to return the logging function to use depending on the current Level to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @dpr exactly, `SLF4J`

Comment: @dpr the code duplication appears when you have 10 `sendEmail` invocations with preceding `LOGGER.xxx("....")`, I think

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the environment you are using, you could implement a logging aspect for the `sendMail` method, that wraps all calls to `sendMail` and logs the message to the correct logger.

This would solve both of your code style problems as it would avoid code duplication and separation of concerns (keep logging and sending the mail separate). It would however introduce an additional level of complexity, if this would be the only usecase for aspects in your application.

Actually I think this is more like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/